# TSQL Update multiple columns with CASE but depending on a value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

this is driving me a bit nuts. I'll explain a simplified version of my problem. I have two tables, source and destination:

```
CREATE TABLE AMG_TDest(
ID INT,
Value1 INT,
Value2 INT,
Value3 INT,
Value4 INT)

CREATE TABLE AMG_TSource(
ID INT,
RowNumber INT,
Value INT)

INSERT INTO AMG_TDest VALUES (1, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0, 0, 0)

INSERT INTO AMG_TSource VALUES (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 3), (1, 4, 4), (2, 1, 10), (2, 2, 20), (2, 3, 30), (2, 4, 40)
```

I want to update Value1, Value2, Value3 and Value4 in Destination table depending on TSource.RowNumber.

In the end what I want to get as a result is this on Destination table:

```
ID V1   V2  V3  V4
1   1   2   3   4
2   10  20  30  40
```

I tried this (with some variations)

```
UPDATE AMG_TDest
SET
    Value1 = CASE WHEN  S.RowNumber = 1  THEN COALESCE(S.Value, 0) ELSE Value1 END,
    Value2 = CASE WHEN  S.RowNumber = 2 THEN COALESCE(S.Value, 0) ELSE Value2 END,
    Value3 = CASE WHEN  S.RowNumber = 3  THEN COALESCE(S.Value, 0) ELSE Value3 END,
    Value4 = CASE WHEN  S.RowNumber = 4  THEN COALESCE(S.Value, 0) ELSE Value4 END
FROM ( SELECT * FROM AMG_TSource ) AS S
INNER JOIN AMG_TDest D ON D.ID = S.ID
```

It just updates the Value1 from first row and Value4 from last row. I've been battling with this for some hours now and I can't make it work. If anyone has suggestions I'm really thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method using a PIVOT

```
;WITH cteX
AS(
    SELECT PVT.ID
         , PVT.Value4
         , PVT.Value3
         , PVT.Value2
         , PVT.Value1 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT S.ID
             , RN ='Value' + CAST(S.RowNumber AS varchar(10))
             , S.[Value]
        FROM dbo.AMG_TSource S
    ) X
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Value) FOR RN IN ([Value1],[Value2],[Value3],[Value4])
    ) PVT
)
UPDATE D
SET D.Value1 = X.Value1
    , D.Value2 = X.Value2
    , D.Value3 = X.Value3
    , D.Value4 = X.Value4
FROM 
    dbo.AMG_TDest   D
INNER JOIN
    cteX            X ON X.ID = D.ID
```

The Pivot chamges the Source dataset like so

```
ID  Value4  Value3  Value2  Value1
1   4       3       2       1
2   40      30      20      10
```

Then all you need to is then join on the `ID` column
for the update to the destination table

Comment: Great! It works. I'll check it in my original USP to see if is there any performance issue. I have many columns and it is a bit kilometric

Comment: I'm happy to help